# Exclude Row with Same ID but Different Secondary Column Value

Tags: sql, oracle, filter

Im trying to exclude a record if the `ID (PK)` is the same but a secondary column value is different.

So in my example below, I have two different codes `E03_Port` and `E12_PortfNotDef` for a single `ID`, so basically, I want to exclude the `E12_PortfNotDef` record if `E01..` through `E04..` codes are triggered.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Code,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code = 'E01_Matured' THEN 1 Else NULL END) AS Matured,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code = 'E02_Terminated' THEN 2 Else NULL END) AS Terminated,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code = 'E03_Port' THEN '3' Else NULL END) AS Port,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code = 'E04_Swap' THEN 4 Else NULL END) AS Swap,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Code = 'E12_PortfNotDef' THEN '12' Else NULL END) AS Port_Not_Def
  FROM EXCLUDED
  GROUP BY ID, Code
)
WHERE COALESCE(Matured, Terminated, Port, Swap Port_Not_Def) IS NOT NULL
AND ID = '120320AC'
ORDER BY ID;
```

Actual Results:

```
    ID              Code            Matured     Terminated   Port Swap  Port_Not_Def
    120320AC      E03_Port             3            
    120320AC      E12_PortfNotDef                                             12
```

Expected Results:

```
    ID              Code           Matured   Terminated     Port    Swap    Port_Not_Def
    120320AC      E03_Port            3
```

Comment: How can ID be the Primary key if you have duplicate values of the same ID?

Answer (score 1):

There's a trivial way might be applied by using `row_number()` window analytic function :

```
SELECT *
 FROM (
       SELECT ID, Code,    
              MAX(CASE WHEN Code = 'E01_Matured' THEN 1 Else NULL END) AS Matured,
              MAX(CASE WHEN Code = 'E02_Terminated' THEN 2 Else NULL END) AS Terminated,
              MAX(CASE WHEN Code = 'E03_Port' THEN '3' Else NULL END) AS Port,
              MAX(CASE WHEN Code = 'E04_Swap' THEN 4 Else NULL END) AS Swap,
              MAX(CASE WHEN Code = 'E12_PortfNotDef' THEN '12' Else NULL END) AS Port_Not_Def,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY ID, Code) AS RN     
         FROM EXCLUDED
        GROUP BY ID, Code)    
 WHERE COALESCE(Matured, Terminated, Port, Swap Port_Not_Def) IS NOT NULL
   AND ID = '120320AC'
   AND RN = 1
 ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Thats a good suggestion but unfortunately it wont work for this because i have many other codes- up to 25. For a single id there could be code 14, 17, 19, etc. I want to keep these but only exclude if E01 - E04 are populated for that ID

Comment: @Manny I think adding also `PARTITION BY Code` solves your problem, and `Code_ID` = `Code`, isn't it?

Comment: Im not familiar with partioning but i tried it and its resulting in 0 records. I was thinking i might have to create a temp table or creating actual logic for Codes E01- E04

Answer (score 0):

I ended up restricting the ID's in the FROM Clause to not show those where Code was E01-E04.